# Sql Query to join 4 tables using if condition or CASE

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 4 tables for the chat.

**Table-1** (main comment table, the user for Table-1 is considered from Table-2)

---

id

comments

---

**Table-2** (when ever new comment is added in Table-1, table-2 will also get updated with the user_id of the commenter)

---

comment_id(reference from Table-1)

user_id

---

**Table-3**(does some other works but related to Table-1 through comment_id)

---

id

column_related_to_table-3

comment_id

user_id

---

**table-4**(does some other works but related to Table-1 through comment_id)

---

id

column_related_to_table-4

comment_id

user_id

---

Now I want to get comment_id's from from all the Tables(Table-2, Table-3, Table-4) and finally get comments using those comment_id's from Table-1 if the particular user in present in either of the tables.

```
SELECT A.id,A.comment,
FROM Table-1 A  
LEFT JOIN Table-2 B 
ON B.comment_id = A.id
LEFT JOIN Table-3 C 
ON C.comment_id = A.id OR C.user_id = {$current_user}
LEFT JOIN Table-4 D
ON D.comment_id = A.id OR D.user_id = {$current_user}
WHERE  B.`user` = {$current_user}
GROUP BY A.`id`
ORDER BY A.`id` DESC
LIMIT 7 OFFSET 0
```

And i tried union of 3 tables as well

```
Select A.id AS cid
FROM Table-1 A
LEFT JOIN Table-2 B
ON B.comment_id = A.id
WHERE B.user_id = {$current_user}
UNION
Select C.comment_id AS cid
FROM Table-3 C
WHERE C.user_id = {$current_user}
UNION
Select D.comment_id AS cid
FROM Table-4 D
WHERE D.user_id = {$current_user}
```

But here I don't know how to get the "GROUP BY A.`id`, ORDER BY A.`id` DESC
LIMIT 7 OFFSET 0" working and don't know how to get the comments from Table-1 using the id's i get from union.

[image]

[image]

Table-1(activity)
Table-2 (comments)
Table-2(comments) id is connected to table-1(activity) as data-id.
I am linking table-2(to know time and commented user etc) in table-1.

Table-3(chat)
The concept here is like one comment can have thread that is represented by chat. It will always be related to comment.
[image]

Table-4(chat_followers)
Here one can ping to other users so whom and all are pinged in the chat will be here
[image]

In the end the idea is to get "all the comments of a users" if he has written that comment or have replied in a chat(Thread for the comment) or if he is pinged by anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want any data other than comment Ids from Tables 2,3,4, why don't you use a simple IN clause?

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 A
WHERE A.id IN 
(SELECT Comment_Id FROM Table2 WHERE.... UNION ALL 
SELECT Comment_ID FROM Table3 WHERE... UNION ALL 
SELECT Comment_Id FROM Table4 WHERE...)
GROUP BY A.`id`
ORDER BY A.`id` DESC
LIMIT 7 OFFSET 0
```

If you do want to use additional columns from the other tables, you can get this working with a LEFT OUTER JOIN:

```
SELECT A.id,A.comment
FROM 
    Table-1 A  LEFT JOIN 
    Table-2 B ON B.comment_id = A.id AND B.User = currentUserId LEFT JOIN 
    Table-3 C ON C.comment_id = A.id AND C.User = currentUserId LEFT JOIN 
    Table-4 D ON D.comment_id = A.id AND D.User = currentUserId
WHERE  B.id IS NOT NULL OR C.id IS NOT NULL OR D.id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY A.`id`
ORDER BY A.`id` DESC
LIMIT 7 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: actually table 2, 3, 4 has other data in columns related to respective tables. i have just shown only columns required.

Comment: Not what your question stated - you said specifically you want to get comment ids from those tables!

Comment: You can add additional joins and still keep the IN clause

Comment: The first query is taking too much time to execute.

Comment: IN is not efficient, but it's easy to read. The left join query can be much faster - esp if you have the right indexing in place

Comment: But while using the left join i am not getting the proper result I need. IN is working just fine but too slow.

Comment: Give more details abt what's wrong in your results using LEFT JOIN and I can guide you

Comment: Hi, I have added all the table and what I want in the main can you please take a look.

Comment: Can I use CASE for this scenario?